# Return whether the cards can be rearranged

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash-map

I solved this question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/hand-of-straights/):

> Alice has a hand of cards, given as an array of integers.  Now she wants to rearrange the cards into groups so that each group is size W, and consists of W consecutive cards.  Return true if and only if she can.  For e.g., for `hand=[1,2,3,6,2,3,4,7,8]` and `W=3`, the answer should be `true`.

as:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isNStraightHand(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        if(nums.size()%k!=0) return false;
        
        map<int, int> _m;
        for(int num: nums) _m[num]++;
        
        while(_m.size()) {
            auto it=_m.begin();
            int count=1;
            int prev=it->first;
            while(count<=k) {
                it->second--;
                if(count>1 && it->first-prev!=1) return false;
                else prev=it->first;
                count++;
                if(it->second==0) {
                    auto backupIt=it;
                    _m.erase(backupIt);     //am I causing UB here?
                }
                it++;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
};
```

This works, but it doesn't look like a sturdy solution. I am curious to know if I am causing Undefined Behavior (UB) when erasing the element above.  Earlier, I just had `_m.erase(it);`, but that wasn't good either.  I think so, since the [official website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) says:

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.

so, when I do a `it++` in the following line, isn't that invalid? That part in particular can probably be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes" it is UB. To fix it just rewrite the part as:

```
if(it->second==0) 
{
    it = _m.erase(it);
}
else
{
     it++;
}
```

Comment: @ALX23z, I am not sure it helps.  If I don't `it++` after erasing the element, I wouldn't be pointing to the next one in the next iteration of the inner `while` loop.

Comment: @J.Doe lookup reference for map::erase https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase it returns following iterator. What I wrote is basically from their example of use of erase.

Comment: good point!  Thank you! :)